# Strange if statement in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm not using php as my main back end language, but sometime I like to test some things on different languages and I saw that this if won't work. Why? $var is string so it exists.

```
$var = '0';

if($var) {
  echo 'a';
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php : See `$x = "0";` line.

Comment: This is a typical construct of interpreted languages... `$var` is tested to resolve to anything not falsy.

Comment: Yes, but then why 'false' is not false?

Comment: Read the documentation linked by @CBroe. It even contain an example using the string `"false"` being evaluated to `true`.

Comment: Because `'false'` is neither, quote, _“the empty string, [or] the string "0"”_

Comment: What I meant by this question is that isn't this just wrong to convert '0' to just 0? It's not that I don't understand what is happening

Comment: @LeoOdishvili It's not converting `'0'` to `0`. It simply treats the `"0"` as `false`.

Comment: Check Syscall's link. Using the if statement as you are does a loose comparison, so the 0 string is treated as a 0 value.

Comment: So if you want to check variable for containing string and there is chance that there can be '0' you should check as it was written in one of answers - isset($var)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP treats `'0'` as equal to `0` which is equal to `false` so your statement reduces to

```
if(false) {
  echo 'a';
}
```